# What is facebook chat bot payload field?

Tags: facebook-chatbot

Can someone explain to me what is the 'payload' field in facebook chatbot button element? I'm new to bot development. Would be great if you can provide an example too.

Answer (score 1):

the 'payload' field is a user-defined field that enables you to call an action whenever a postback with this payload is received.

for example; if I create a persistent menu in my bot that contains 2 buttons: 'Home' and 'Contact', and the payload for each of them is the same as the name of the button. When a user clicks on the 'Home' button, a postback is sent with the payload 'Home'. In that case you can create an action that takes the user to the 'Home' part of the bot.

for more about postbacks and payload, go to:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/postback-button
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback-received

make sure to create a function in your main 'post' function that handles the postback. The code below is from a bot tutorial in Python

```
# Post function to handle facebook messages
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # converts the text payload into a python dictionary
    incoming_message = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    # facebook recommends going through every entry since they might send
    # multiple messages in a single call during high load
    for entry in incoming_message['entry']:
        for message in entry['messaging']:
            # check to make sure the received call is a message call
            # this might be delivery, optin, postback for other events

            if 'message' in message:
                pprint(message)
                ### add here the rest of the code that will be handled when the bot receives a message ###

            if 'postback' in message:
                # print the message in terminal
                pprint(message)
                ### add here the rest of the code that will be handled when the bot receives a postback ###
```